# Incrementar de 5 en 5 en un for

Tags: java

Hola tengo una pequeña duda, ¿se puede en un for recorrer un String[] e ir incrementando de 5 en 5?. Tengo en el String[] en las primeras 5 posiciones unas lineas que forman parte de una noticia (por ejemplo).

en plan asi:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vecString.size(); (incrementar i en 5)){
}
```

Y otra duda que tengo es sobre SimpleDateFormat, tengo en un txt, contenido donde figuran unas fechas, al leer el .txt y trocearlo (StringTokenizer) y guardarlo en un String[], las fechas las leería bien¿?. No sé muy bien que hacer con SimpleDateFormat, ¿podeís explicarmelo?.

Un saludo y gracias, espero que podáis ayudarme.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Si tienes 2 dudas es mejor hacer 2 preguntas separadas. Por otra parte, es bueno que agregues el código de lo que ya hayas intentado y expliques la dificultad o problema encontrado y el resultado deseado. Puedes leer [mcve]. En cuanto a tu primera duda, si que puedes incrementar de 5 en 5, por ejemplo: `for(int i = 0; i < valor; i  += 5)` o  `for(int i = 0; i < valor; i = i + 5)`. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

respecto a tu primera duda:
Para iterar el ciclo for de 5 en 5,

```
for(int i = 0; i < vecString.size(); i=i+5){
    //tu código
}
```

o bien:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vecString.size(); i+=5){
    //tu código
}
```

Ahora en relación a tu segunda duda:
Suponiendo que has logrado cargar y trocear las fechas desde el archivo de texto, puedes usar la clase `SimpleDateFormat` para darle formato a la o las strings que quieras.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParsePosition;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String myText = "2019-01-01 10:30:56"; // string obtenida del archivo txt
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate = formatter.parse(myText, new ParsePosition(0)); //
        System.out.println(myDate);
    }
}
```

En la consola deberías ver la representación de `myDate`:

```
Tue Jan 01 10:30:56 GMT 2019
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la documentación de Java:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Vaya, casi al mismo tiempo. Te invito a leer [answer], aunque tu respuesta está bastante detallada. Lo importante es tener en cuenta que para responder una pregunta, el OP debe demostrar que lo ha intentado e incluir el código de lo que haya intentado. Es por eso que en mi comentario en la pregunta se lo recalco. Igual tu respuesta es muy válida. Saludos